# Reactjs Axios File upload

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to upload file to my .net core backend, file successfully uploads when i use postman or the swagger ui buh when i try using axios it keeps returning

> request failed with status code 400

Here is my reactjs code snippet

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", payload.img,);
formData.append("name", payload.name);
var config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${payload.token}`,
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
};
let res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/merchant/logo`, formData, config);
```

Please i have tried everything it seems not to be working I don't know what to do.

Here is my model class

```
public class Logo
{
public string name{ get; set; }
public IFormFile image{ get; set; }
}
```

here is my .Net core Action

```
var logoName = merchant.Identifier + "." + logoDto.Image.FileName.Split(".")[1];
 string oldPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/logo", merchant.Logo);
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/logo", logoName);
if (File.Exists(oldPath)) File.Delete(oldPath);
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
await logoDto.Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with how you are trying with the postman? with necessary headers and body payload?

Comment: Can you share the bakend? 400 indicates the model bind error. And `payload.img` is a file, `payload.name` is a string?

Comment: I can send data to the background normally with these code. Can you share the action?

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear, but I want to share the corret method to realize it.

1. Ensure `payload.img` is a single file.
2. IF you use `[ApiController]`, it needs to be formulated `[FromForm]`.

   ```
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class ValController:Controller
   {
      [HttpPost("get")]
      public IActionResult get([FromForm]Logo logo)
      {
        return Ok();
      }
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: @bootes void, could you accept this answer, or have any other issues?